# Should actors for resource connection pool be long or short living?

Tags: akka, actor, lifetime

We are designing system in Akka, and part of its work is to perform operations using limited number of connections from a shared pool. It feels reasonable to create a connection supervisor actor that will instantiate child actors on demand limiting its number to the size of the connection pool. But should child actors be created for each individual operation and stopped once they complete their work, or they should follow their respective connections, i.e. in practice live for the lifetime of the application staying idle when there are no requests.

My first thought is that as long as creating actors is cheap (and it is) the child actor maintenance logic will be easier if each of them is only assigned a single job and terminates as soon as it's finished. This however complicates management of pending requests in case there are no idle actors available and requests must be queued. What I dislike in the alternative approach (long living child actors) is that there is a risk of losing pending requests if an actor dies having non-empty mailbox.

Comment: Have you looked at Routers within Akka yet?  A dynamically sized pool with a min size of something like 1 might be a good fit for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I've looked at Routers and this is what I am planning to use to manage child actors. But I am still uncertain what would be the best lifecycle strategy: keep actors alive in between requests or create terminate them after each single job.